# Aggregation matrices in subgroups

Tags: r, matrix

I have few matrix. They are in few subgroups (I have vector which shows these subgroups - for example matrix 1 and 2 are in group A, matrix 3 in group B, matrix 4,5,6 in group C, and so on). I want to add all matrices in one group to have new matrix.
To sum up: input - matrices in some subgroups, output - matrices in amount of dimension of vector of subgroups)

How can I do it? I tried with 'aggregate' and 'tapply', but it doesn't work:

aggregate(list1,list2,func)

where

list1 contains all my matrices

list2 contains subgroups

func - my function to add matrices (it could be standard "+")

EXAMPLE

```r
> subgroups=c(1,1,2,3,3,3)
> M1<-matrix(c(2,3,1,4),2,2)
> M1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    3    4
> M2<-matrix(c(3,0,1,1),2,2)
> M2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    1
[2,]    0    1
> M3<-matrix(c(0,0,1,1),2,2)
> M3
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1
> M4<-matrix(c(0,2,-9,-3),2,2)
> M4
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0   -9
[2,]    2   -3
> M5<-matrix(c(0,0,1,1),2,2)
> M5
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1
> M6<-matrix(c(-1,2,2,1),2,2)
> M6
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1    2
[2,]    2    1
> result=list(M1+M2,M3,M4+M5+M6)
> result
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    2
[2,]    3    5

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1   -6
[2,]    4   -1
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data for us with expected output? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Use `tapply` as shown:

```
L <- list(M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6)  # or mget(ls(pattern = "^M\\d$"))
tapply(L, subgroups, Reduce, f = "+")
```

giving:

```
$`1`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    2
[2,]    3    5

$`2`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1

$`3`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1   -6
[2,]    4   -1
```